# How to write method that return an object pointer, function is declared in another header

Tags: c++, templates, header

I want to write a class like this. How can I define findMin and findMax function in another cpp file?

```
template <typename Comparable>
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
    struct BinaryNode
    {
        Comparable element;
        BinaryNode *left;
        BinaryNode *right;

        BinaryNode(const Comparable & theElement, BinaryNode *lt, BinaryNode *rt)
        : element(theElement), left(lt), right(rt){}
    };

    BinaryNode * findMin(BinaryNode *t) const;
    BinaryNode * findMax(BinaryNode *t) const;
}
```

Comment: That question doesn't contains the type that return type is a pointer to object I think

Comment: The return type is absolutely irrelevant, `BinarySearchTree` is a class template.

Comment: But I can't use like this: template<typename Comparable>
BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::BinaryNode *
BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::findMax(BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::BinaryNode *t) const

Comment: All of the answers you seek are in the linked answer, give up, it isn't possible.